# Kafka spout integration

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I am using kafka 0.10.1.1 and storm 1.0.2. In the storm documentation  for kafka integration , i can see that offsets are still maintained using zookeeper as we are initializing kafka spout using zookeeper servers.
How can i bootstrap the spout using kafka servers .Is there any example for this . 
Example from storm docs

```
    BrokerHosts hosts = new ZkHosts(zkConnString);
SpoutConfig spoutConfig = new SpoutConfig(hosts, topicName, "/" + topicName, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
spoutConfig.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
KafkaSpout kafkaSpout = new KafkaSpout(spoutConfig);
```

This option using zookeeper is working fine and is consuming the messages . but i was not able to see the consumer group or storm nodes as consumers in kafkamanager ui .

Alternate approach tried is this .

```
KafkaSpoutConfig<String, String> kafkaSpoutConfig = newKafkaSpoutConfig();

KafkaSpout<String, String> spout = new KafkaSpout<>(kafkaSpoutConfig);

 private static KafkaSpoutConfig<String, String> newKafkaSpoutConfig() {

        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(KafkaSpoutConfig.Consumer.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(KafkaSpoutConfig.Consumer.GROUP_ID, GROUP_ID);
        props.put(KafkaSpoutConfig.Consumer.KEY_DESERIALIZER,
                "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put(KafkaSpoutConfig.Consumer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER,
                "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put(KafkaSpoutConfig.Consumer.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT, "true");

        String[] topics = new String[1];
        topics[0] = topicName;

        KafkaSpoutStreams kafkaSpoutStreams =
                new KafkaSpoutStreamsNamedTopics.Builder(new Fields("message"), topics).build();

        KafkaSpoutTuplesBuilder<String, String> tuplesBuilder =
                new KafkaSpoutTuplesBuilderNamedTopics.Builder<>(new TuplesBuilder(topicName)).build();

        KafkaSpoutConfig<String, String> spoutConf =
                new KafkaSpoutConfig.Builder<>(props, kafkaSpoutStreams, tuplesBuilder).build();

        return spoutConf;
    }
```

But this solution is showing CommitFailedException after reading few messages from kafka.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storm-kafka writes consumer information in a different location and different format in zookeeper with common kafka client. So you can't see it in kafkamanager ui.

You can find some other monitor tools, like 
https://github.com/keenlabs/capillary.

Answer (score 1):

On your alternate approach, you're likely getting `CommitFailedException` due to:

```
props.put(KafkaSpoutConfig.Consumer.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT, "true");
```

Up to Storm 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT (and since 1.0.6) - 
*KafkaConsumer autocommit is unsupported*

From the docs:

> Note that KafkaConsumer autocommit is unsupported. The
>   KafkaSpoutConfig constructor will throw an exception if the
>   "enable.auto.commit" property is set, and the consumer used by the
>   spout will always have that property set to false. You can configure
>   similar behavior to autocommit through the setProcessingGuarantee
>   method on the KafkaSpoutConfig builder.

References:

- http://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/storm-kafka-client.html
- http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.6/storm-kafka-client.html